# Unable to Send Cart Details to Paypal

Tags: javascript, paypal, e-commerce, paypal-ipn, cart

I am using this https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/minicart/3.0.6/minicart.min.js script to render a cart for my e-commerce website. This works pretty fine as I can add and remove items from the cart and view the subtotal. However, when it comes to linking with paypal (the main reason I think it was designed), I am unable to submit the cart details, i.e. all items' names and prices along with the total to paypal for processing payment. Can someone have a look and help me understand how to do this. At least, retrieve the price and quantity of each item and the total. If I can access these at any point in my application, that would be a great start.

Please find here a snippet of my use of the script to add an item to cart. [image: Loop to create items with quantity and an add to cart button]

This is my inclusion of the javascript.[image]

This is how it looks like in view.[image: Item Added to Cart]

Answer (score 0):

You have add the shopping cart variables to pass your cart details to PayPal

Please find the below link,

https://developer.paypal.com/docs/classic/paypal-payments-standard/integration-guide/Appx_websitestandard_htmlvariables/#shopping-cart-variables

Comment: Can you please suggest how you would write the HTML form so that on submitting it sends to  Paypal the contents of the cart. When I chnage the action to 'https://www.paypal.com/cgi-bin/webscr and replace add with display and try to submit, it tells me that my cart is empty. Actually, the cart has items. It is not just submitting them. Even if you can just understand the minicart.min.js and show me how to access subtotal and item quantity at any given time, then I can work with that.

Comment: I will check and send you a sample.